# Wordpress get post id (article id) in admin add post page

Tags: wordpress

How can I get next post link in wordpress admin side (in edit post page)?
I need to get next post link in admin side not on codding. So please tell me.

Thanks,
AJ

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, wordpress have a plugin, you can simply use it. After using it you will get links on edit screen to `next post` and `previous post` if exist. The plugin is [admin post navigation](http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-post-navigation/)